# NAT KeepAlive Package in Android

Tags: android, udp, nat, keep-alive, tcp-keepalive

I wonder that NAT keepalive can work with TCP packet or not? Or only for UDP package.
NAT keepalive package & keepalive package are different?

I have read post:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.onsip.com/voip-resources/voip-fundamentals/what-is-nat-keepalive%3fhs_amp=true

In this post, they said that "NAT keepalive is a feature that sends very tiny data packets, called UDP packets"

Comment: There is TCP keep alive, which is sending TCP packets with zero payload on idle connections.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you for your reply, but in this post, they point out that NAT keep alive is an UDP package. So I wonder at that point. And what is the different between keepalive and nat keepalive package?

Comment: The "NAT keepalive" they talk about is using UDP since the SIP protocol they use is UDP. If the would use SIP over TCP (which is possible too) then they could use the builtin keepalive mechanism of TCP, i.e. TCP keepalive. The idea is the same - regularly send packets to keep the NAT state alive. Although the main purpose of TCP keepalive is to detect broken idle TCP connections, keeping the NAT state alive is a useful side effect.